# Can I publish app to Apple Store through iOS Developer University Program

Tags: ios, apple-developer-account

I am trying to register In Apple developer program but apple reject my application by saying your website is not valid for your legal entity name and give me link to register through iOS Developer University Program. My question is that can I able to publish app to apple store through this program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will not be able to publish app to apple store through this program.

So, What included in this program?

These are:-

1) **Student Development Team** :
The iOS Developer University Program allows instructors and professors to create a development team with up to 200 students.

2)**Development Resources** :
With the suite of sophisticated and elegant tools included in the iOS SDK, and a wide-range of resources available on the Apple Developer website, students participating in the class will have everything they need to create innovative applications for iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch.

3)**Test on iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch** :
Students can test and debug their applications using Xcode’s graphical debugger, or collect real-time performance data in Instruments’ timeline view. To see their work in action and ensure proper functionality, students can install their applications directly on iPad, iPhone and iPod touch.

4)**Sharing Applications** :
The iOS Developer University Program allows students and professors within the same team to share their development applications with each other through email, or by posting them to a private website for presentation and grading purposes.